# Trying to use Linux menuconfig with yocto/morty

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, openembedded

We are working on our own embedded Yocto build and would like to use menuconfig from the Linux kernel to configure some device drivers.  We would like to add PPP support to our image.

From the build directory we try

```
bitbake virtual/kernel -c menuconfig
```

That tries to launch menuconfig but results in the following error:

```
Failed to execute child process "oe-gnome-terminal-phonehome" (No such file or directory)
```

We are fairly new to working on a linux kernal.  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: It seems some environment setting issue. Try this https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/129527/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT (new "answer")

I just realized that according to the error message posted, starting your additional graphical terminal failed. This is according to [1] a known problem in your Python version [2]. And occurs according to [3] only on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS since the `oe-gnome-terminal-phonehome` stuff was added [4].

Therefore you may try to participate in finding an upstream accepted solution on this issue.

[1] https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/129527/

[2] https://bugs.python.org/issue8557

[3] https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10312

[4] https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/commit/?id=c706bfbabbf9f7caf2cf509eb91381fb49aa44cb

---

### OLD answer

I'm using *menuconfig* in a *devshell*. This works (at least for jethro) perfectly well.

Therefore, in your bitbake build directory execute:

```
bitbake virtual/kernel -c devshell
```

Then a new terminal window should pop up standing somewhere inside `TEMPDIR` of your build directory. In this shell you should now be able to execute:

```
make menuconfig
```

Answer (score 4):

open **meta/lib/oe/terminal.py**
and replace

```
sh_cmd = "oe-gnome-terminal-phonehome " + pidfile + " " + sh_cmd
```

with

```
sh_cmd = bb.utils.which(os.getenv('PATH'), "oe-gnome-terminal-phonehome") + " " + pidfile + " " + sh_cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to edit terminal.py partially worked for me.  I had to also install the two ncurses libraries.

```
:~/fsl$ vi sources/poky/meta/lib/oe/terminal.py
-           sh_cmd = "oe-gnome-terminal-phonehome " + pidfile + " " + sh_cmd
+           sh_cmd = bb.utils.which(os.getenv('PATH'), "oe-gnome-terminal-phonehome") + " " + pidfile + " " + sh_cmd
```

I then had to install ncurses

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
sudo apt-get install libncursesw5-dev
```